# How to stack elements in CSS Grid one on top of another?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to stack elements one on top of another, using CSS Grid.

**Here is my code.**

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    border: 0.1rem black solid;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 10rem;

    img {
        width: 10rem;
        height: 10rem;
    }

    h2 {
        grid-column: 2 / 3;
        grid-row: 1 / 2;
    }

    h3 {
        grid-column: 2 / 3;
        grid-row: 1 / 2;
    }

    h4 {
        font-style: italic;
        grid-column: 2 / 3;
        grid-row: 1 / 2;
    }

    p {
        text-align: justify;
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
        grid-row: 2 / 3;
    }
`;

const Card = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <img src={img} alt="album" />
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <h3>Sit Amet Consectetur</h3>
            <h4>
                Vero iusto distinctio natus esse quos incidunt nihil consectetur
                consequatur suscipit
            </h4>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Delectus sit ex et, consectetur consequatur suscipit placeat ut
                corrupti facere voluptatem ratione, vero iusto distinctio natus
                esse quos incidunt nihil.
            </p>
        </Wrapper>
    );
};
```

**h2, h3, h4 are overlapping one another... Here's how it looks in the Firefox DevTools...**

[image: DevTools]

**I want to stack h2, h3, h4 one on another, in order h2 -> h3 -> h4, at column 2 / 3 and row 1 /2 ... How do I do it ? Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `h2`, `h3` and `h4` are overlapping each other because that's what you told them to do.

Here's your code:

```
h2 {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

h3 {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

h4 {
    font-style: italic;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
```

You place all three elements in the same grid cell (`grid-column: 2 / 3` /  `grid-row: 1 / 2`), so they overlay each other.

To make them stack vertically, here are two options:

(1) You can wrap the headings in a container, which becomes the grid item, like this:

```css
Wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 10rem;
  border: 0.1rem black solid;
}

img {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

section {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

h4 {
  font-style: italic;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<Wrapper>
  <img src={img} alt="album" />
  <section>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <h3>Sit Amet Consectetur</h3>
    <h4>
      Vero iusto distinctio natus esse quos incidunt nihil consectetur consequatur suscipit
    </h4>
  </section>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus sit ex et, consectetur consequatur suscipit placeat ut corrupti facere voluptatem ratione, vero iusto distinctio natus esse quos incidunt nihil.
  </p>
</Wrapper>
```

OR, (2) you can adjust your grid to provide rows for each heading. Something like this:

```css
Wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto 10rem;
  border: 0.1rem black solid;
}

img {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

h2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

h3 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

h4 {
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  font-style: italic;
}

p {
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<Wrapper>
  <img src={img} alt="album" />
  <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <h3>Sit Amet Consectetur</h3>
  <h4>
    Vero iusto distinctio natus esse quos incidunt nihil consectetur consequatur suscipit
  </h4>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus sit ex et, consectetur consequatur suscipit placeat ut corrupti facere voluptatem ratione, vero iusto distinctio natus esse quos incidunt nihil.
  </p>
</Wrapper>
```